# Do i have to set InAppPurchase for paypal, Alipay payments

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have implemented Paypal payment in my application for downloading songs. Do i need to setup InAppPurchase (IAP) for Paypal or PayTm or Alipay.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is NO.

> If you want to sell any digital goods or content inside your app you
>   should use In App Purchases. Apple takes almost 30% of commission on
>   each In App Purchase.
>
> Now, if you want to sell any physical goods or services than Apple
>   requires you to use any of 3rd party Payment systems.

Comment: In my application i'm upgrading my plan from free to paid , to do this i did paypal , DO i need to use IAP.

Comment: Not at all.. Your payments are fully dependant on paypal.

Comment: Please find below message got from Apple team 
We noticed that your app offers a subscription with a mechanism other than the in-app purchase API.

Please see attached screenshots for details.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please revise your app to ensure that the subscription for products used within the app is offered using the in-app purchase API, with the exception of the content specified in guideline 3.1.3 of the App Store Review Guidelines.

Comment: As per Apple's message, you must only use IAP for content/functionality delivered in the app.  Other payment methods are not permitted.